# Hey need help with a mysql exception i am getting abt communication link failure

Tags: mysql, client-server

Hey guys, i m running a mysql server on my host machine.
The code is provided below.When i try 2 run the same code from another machine connected to the same router.I get the exception that I hav provided below the code.

Please help.

Code:-
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

```
public class Login{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Connection conn = null;
String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+br.readLine()+":3306/";
String dbName = "p2p";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String userName = "root";
String password = "123";
System.out.println("Please input Username:");
String user=br.readLine();
System.out.println("Please input Password:");
String pass=br.readLine();

try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
  String sql="select password from newuser where username='"+user+"'";
  Statement stmt=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;

  try{
      stmt=conn.createStatement();
      rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
     if(rs.next())
     {
         if(rs.getString("password").equals(pass))
          System.out.println("true");
         else
          System.out.println("false");
     }
     else System.out.println("false");
     }
  catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
  conn.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Exception:-

```
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driv
er has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1
112)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:346)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2334)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2
371)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2163)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:374)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:525)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171)
        at Login.main(login.java:20)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.1.23306: 192.168.1.23306
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1128)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1098)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1061)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.ja
va:244)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:295)
        ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the machines on the same network or allowed in the same VLAN. The error that you are getting means the program cannot even see the MySQL server. Another possibility, check the account on MySQL and make sure that the both servers are in the allowed HOSTS for the account.

Comment: i updated the privilege table in the mysql server to allow that particular user in.

Comment: Did that work? Other people may get this error and may want to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace has this line:

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:171) at Login.main(login.java:20) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 192.168.1.23306: 192.168.1.23306 at
```

Which means your Java process doesn't know about host address 192.168.1.23306

Comment: the mysql server is on 192.168.1.2

Comment: Well the stack trace says Unknown host for 192.168.1.23306. That means either there is no MySQL running on 192.168.1.2:3306 or there is some problem in reading hostname from System.in. Can you change this line url to:
String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/";
and try running you code.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys, i got the error.
Instead of using br.readLine() when i put the actual ip of the mysql server m/c the program runs.

Comment: In that case would you please mark my answer as "accepted"? If you see my answer and the comment I did suggest you precisely that, i.e.to change your url to String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/"; in your code.